# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J

Tags: maven, google-api, guava, service-accounts, bytestream

I'm getting this "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J" error while using ServiceCredentials.fromStream() method. Anyone here faced this and know a fix? TIA

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>[title]</groupId>
<artifactId>calendar-event-consumer</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>Service that listens for events in a queue to push them 
to an external API</description>
<inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
<maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<scala.version>2.11.5</scala.version>
<scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>${scala.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Test -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
  <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.16</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
  <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback- 
classic -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<!--JSON parsing-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
  <artifactId>json4s-native_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!--Google Calendar API-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
  <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
  <version>v3-rev254-1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
  <version>0.20.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>23.0</version>
</dependency>

<!--Slick -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.slick</groupId>
  <artifactId>slick_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java - 
->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
  <artifactId>config</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.slick</groupId>
  <artifactId>slick-hikaricp_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <args>
        <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
        <arg>128</arg>
      </args>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>testCompile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <args>
            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>

<arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
          </args>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <useFile>false</useFile>
      <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
      <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
      <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
      <includes>
        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
        <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>maven</executable>
      <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.qpercom.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Error Log:

> 17:40:54.163 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO  c.q.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEventConsumer - Received message of type class
>   com.qpercom.model.CreateOrUpdateEventMessage on event (185,
>   omis19demo) 17:40:54.626 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO 
>   com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - googleApiDb - Started.
>   17:40:55.553 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO  c.q.c.google.GoogleCalendarPusher
>       - Creating event in Google Calendar 17:40:55.690 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO  c.q.c.google.GoogleCalendarPusher - Instantiating Google
>   Calendar Service... 17:40:57.063 [pool-1-thread-3] ERROR
>   c.q.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEventConsumer - Failed pushing event. The
>   message has been re-queued. Trace of exception:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J
>   17:40:57.065 [pool-1-thread-3] ERROR
>   c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler - Consumer
>   com.qpercom.consumer.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEventConsumer$$anon$1@56acb716
>   (amq.ctag-CJwhF_0CeOmwK1kBKrQLXw) method handleDelivery for channel
>   AMQChannel(amqp://zdMBDgTdd9fMMJft@3.249.159.145:5672/,1) threw an
>   exception for channel
>   AMQChannel(amqp://zdMBDgTdd9fMMJft@3.249.159.145:5672/,1)
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J  at
>   com.google.api.client.http.ConsumingInputStream.close(ConsumingInputStream.java:40)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._closeInput(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:237)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.close(ParserBase.java:345)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.close(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:808)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonParser.close(JacksonParser.java:50)
>     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:365)
>     at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:337)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:444)
>     at
>   com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:447)
>     at
>   com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:157)
>     at
>   com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:145)
>     at
>   com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getRequestMetadata(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:603)
>     at
>   com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:91)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:88)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:300)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>     at
>   com.qpercom.calendar.google.GoogleCalendarPusher.colorIdFor(GoogleCalendarPusher.scala:145)
>     at
>   com.qpercom.calendar.google.GoogleCalendarPusher.doCreate(GoogleCalendarPusher.scala:54)
>     at
>   com.qpercom.calendar.google.GoogleCalendarPusher.doCreate(GoogleCalendarPusher.scala:25)
>     at
>   com.qpercom.calendar.AbstractAPICalendarPusher.pushCreateOrUpdate(AbstractAPICalendarPusher.scala:74)
>     at com.qpercom.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:26)  at
>   com.qpercom.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:22)   at
>   com.qpercom.consumer.rabbitmq.RabbitMQEventConsumer$$anon$1.handleDelivery(RabbitMQEventConsumer.scala:49)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:149)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:100)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Can you post at last your `pom.xml`? Which version of `com.google.guava` are you using? Java version? The method `ByteStreams.exhaust` is only available in versions higher than 20.0

Comment: I'm using version 23.0. I used different version but no luck

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace and your pom.xml?

Comment: updated the xml and log for you. TIA

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With some IDE there's a plugin to debug this kind of case.
[image]

Anyway `google-api-client 1.22.0`, as you can see, depends on `guava-jdk5 17`. That version is in conflict with `google-out-library.oath2-http` that need version of guava > 20

Try to modify your pom.xml like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

That produce this:

[image]

With this, you're excluding the old version and use version 23.0, instead of 17.0. I hope it helps.

Comment: How to achieve this in gradle.

Comment: @datastax, sorry never used gradle, try looking [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html), base logic sems similar, or try to post yoru own question

Comment: I had swagger as dependency which also included guava, this helped:
```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>```

Answer (score 5):

I had swagger as dependency which also included guava, this helped:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved with dependency management.

You can read related article here : [link](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-version-collision)

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>//version that you want</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```