# NoSuchMethodError with Guava , GCP Cloud Storage & Datastax

Tags: cassandra, google-cloud-storage, guava, datastax-java-driver, spring-cloud-gcp

***java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(Ljava/io/InputStream;)J***

Getting above error msg , when using **Guava - 18.0v** with **Cloud Storage - 2.2.2v**:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>18.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

If I use **Guava - 23v** with **Datastax -3.2.0v** I'm getting below error msg:

> ***java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback***

so Cloud storage needs Guava version above 20 , but DataStax needs version below 20 , so either thing is working at a time but I want both the things.

My code:

```
 StorageOptions options = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
      .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
      .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials
           .fromStream(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_JSON_KEY))).build();
 Storage storage = options.getService();
 Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, OBJECT_NAME);
 ReadChannel r = blob.reader();
```

Answer (score 1):

3.2.0 seems like a very old version of Cassandra driver from 2017 -- try upgrading to the latest in this major version, [3.11.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core).

It also looks like the driver switched packages to [com.datastackx.oss:java-driver-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core) and moved to the major version 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to reproduce your error using the code and dependencies you have provided.

[image]

and was able to resolve the issue by using these version.

```js
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Output:
[image]

It is also advisable to use the latest version of [DataStax](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core) when you're using Guava 20.0 and above.

Comment: Have you tested on intellij  ?

Comment: I haven't tested it using IntelliJ. I tested in cloud shell. @Anilkumar

Comment: I found similar issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597801/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-io-bytestreams-exhaustljava-io-i) stack post that you might want to check.